# Wrong layout using JqueryUi in the datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, layout, date

I have this simple code, like that on the official site.

```
    <html>
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.all.css">
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demos.css">
    <script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="demo">
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Obviously in the same folder I've moved the interested files and all works ok.
But the layout is awful, because sure miss something.
My output is this:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/wrongdate.png/

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you also moved the `images` folder?

Comment: No. I found smothness theme and the folder "image".
Now where I can move it correctly?
I have to change any paths?

Comment: This folder should be in the same folder as your jQuery UI CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

I dare say it's the style file: you probably have an incorrect path for the file or the file is corrupted. See the following two examples:

1. without css: http://jsfiddle.net/william/5Xa8f
2. with css: http://jsfiddle.net/william/5Xa8f/2/

To confirm it is the problem, simply replace `jquery.ui.all.css` with `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css`, and see if the problem is fixed.